# Ruby on Rails-Param is missing or the value is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a webpage that acts as a parking lot of sorts. /new is the page where we can add cars to the "parking lot", but when submitting the form I encounter this error on the controller:

param is missing or the value is empty: carlog

Here is the code for the controller:

```
class CarLogsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def new
    @carlog = CarLog.new
  end

  def create
    @carlog = CarLog.new(carlog_params) #Error here
  end

  def carlog_params
    params.require(:carlog).permit! #Error here
  end

  def show
    @carlogs = CarLog.all
  end

  def destroy
    @carlog= CarLog.find(params[:id])
    @carlog.destroy()

    redirect_to show_path
  end
end
```

The respective view code for the page is this

```
<h1>New</h1>
<%= form_tag "/carlogs/create" do %>
<p>Plate number:
<input type="text" name="platenumber" /></p>
<p>Brand:
<select name="brand">
<option value="Toyota">Toyota</option>
<option value="Honda">Honda</option>
<option value="BMW">BMW</option>
</select></p>
<p>Slot number
<input type="text" name="slotnumber" /> </p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="istaken" value="true" /> Is taken?</p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<% end %>
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: Why aren't you using rails' machinery for building forms? `form_for`, `f.select` and their friends?

Comment: Also, using `permit!`? This defeats the purpose of params whitelisting (which is this method is for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your method as like below.

```
def carlog_params
    params.require(:carlog).permit(:platenumber,:brand,:slotnumber,:istaken)
end
```

and update your form with this.

```
<h1>New</h1>
<%= form_tag "/carlogs/create" do %>
  <p>Plate number:
     <input type="text" name="carlog[platenumber]" />
  </p>
  <p>Brand:
     <select name="carlog[brand]">
        <option value="Toyota">Toyota</option>
        <option value="Honda">Honda</option>
        <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
     </select>
  </p>
  <p>Slot number
     <input type="text" name="carlog[slotnumber]" />
  </p>
  <p>
     <input type="checkbox" name="carlog[istaken]" value="true" /> Is taken?
  </p>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<% end %>
```

I suggest please use rails form and its input tag for form. don't use pure html form.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
<input type="text" name="carlog[platenumber]" /></p>
```

the name should have `carlog[platenumber]` I think that is missing.

Comment: I did what you said. The error now reads: unknown attribute 'platenumber' for CarLog.

Comment: @Kevin: well, seems that your carlog objects don't have platenumber property

Answer (score 2):

Actually the view code is actually in violation of rails standards as it is not binding the for to a resource, ideally if you bind the form to a resource you wouldn't have this issue. Check the code attached,

```
<h1>New</h1>
<%= form_for @carlog do |f| %>

  <%= f.text_field :platenumber %>
  <%= f.select :brand, [['Toyota', 'Toyota'], ['Honda', 'Honda'], ['BMW', 'BMW']] %>
  <%= f.text_field :slotnumber %>
  <%= f.check_box :istaken %>

  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two immediate corrections:

You should change to:

```
def carlog_params
  params.permit! # or to be explicit params.permit(:platenumber, :brand, :slotnumber, :istaken)
end
```

Then, if you're using the rails router, your action shouldn't be going to `carlogs/create`, rather `/carlogs`

```
#routes.rb
resources :carlogs, only: [:create]
```

You would need the `params.require` if you were binding a model to the form, with a `form_for`

Answer (score 1):

This error means that this parameter name is not available in your params hash. This could be due to the fact that you are not binding the form_for element directly to the @carlog object you create in new method. Before you do anything inspect the params hash to see what are the available values in it.

Your form_for should look like this, example,

```
<%= form_for @carlog do |f| %>

     <%= f.text_field :name %>

     <%= f.submit "Submit" %>

<% end %>
```